# Array of props in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Javascript I can have heterogenous arrays such as:

```
var ex = ['name', 12, true];
console.log(ex);
```

In Vue JS within a single file template I can define props for a component in the `<script></script` section by the following:

```
export default{
props: ['myprop']
}
```

or by having the props listed as an object to validate the type

```
export default{
  props: {
    myprop: String
  }
}
```

Now my question is in vue listing an array of types like `myprop: [String,Array]` lists multiple valid types for the property.

My question is how can I validate against the content of the array at the props level?

For instance taking ex in the pattern of string,number,boolean and a count of 3. Is there a way to make any value that comes into the prop be invalid if it's not this form?

So if I got some data in the form of `[true, 12, 'name']` it'd be invalid. 
But ex would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow, you want to use a custom property validator function. Something like:

```
props: {
  myprop: {
    type: Array,
    validator: value => {
       return /* test value length, indices types, etc here as truthy/falsy */;
    }
  }
}
```

The type property is just a simple validation against type, the custom validator allows you to customize exactly what constitutes a valid property for your component.